# Recreating version of code on the fly in Git

Tags: git

I am working on a project where I analyse source code on every git push. I am looking for ways to improve performance/scalability.

The easy implementation would be to do a "git checkout" on the specific version of the code (commit) I want to analyse. This will deploy all files on the hard disk and then I can read all files one by one and analyse them. This however involves a lot of IO and it would render ineffective any attempt to parallelise the algorithm that analyses the code.

My understanding of Git internals is that git stores the files as "blob" objects (which are kept as files on the disk in .git folder). In some cases it may be storing only the diff between versions to save disk space. So essentially having to do at least one read per file cannot be avoided.

I'm wondering though if there is a way to recreate the content of all files from these blob, same as git does with "git checkout", but instead of deploying the files on the disk, the content of all files would be passed as one input stream into the algorithm, skipping the extra Write/Read operations. The program can then parallelise execution of the algorithm as required/possible for improved performance.

Any thoughs on how I can achieve this? Is there a git "plumbing" tool/command that can help with that, or do I have to look into git's source code?

Comment: `git show <treeish>:<file>` shows you the file at a given commit; perhaps you could start there?

Comment: Maybe `git fast-export` will give you what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the best option for achieving native performance and not having to call git itself, is to use the libgit2 library that implements git core methods and has several language bindings available. The equivalents of `git ls-tree <treeish>` and `git show <treeish>:<file>` in this language would do the specific task in the question.

https://libgit2.github.com

"libgit2 is a portable, pure C implementation of the Git core methods provided as a re-entrant linkable library with a solid API, allowing you to write native speed custom Git applications in any language which supports C bindings."